# Backbone View is not a constructor error in Webpack due to import order

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack

I have a backbone view in 1 file which I am trying to instantiate in another, 'entry' file. An output file is bundled using Webpack and the entry file is loaded first in the output file, before the view code. Something like this:

index.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Book } from './views/Book';

$(document).ready(function () {
  new Book();
});
```

Book.js

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';

const Book = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  template: _.template('<%= name %>'),

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

export default Book;
```

On running the project, I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__views_Book__.Book is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__views_Book__.Book is not a constructor
```

When running webpack, I get this warning:

```
WARNING in ./js/index.js
5:6-10 "export 'Book' was not found in './views/Book'
```

I saw some posts on circular dependencies, but don't think that is the problem here. Can someone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
export default Book
```

then you need to load it this way

```
import Book from './views/Book';
```

---

```
export Book
```

would work with

```
import { Book } from './views/Book';
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed this a while ago, but the 'view is not a constructor' error remains. I thought they might be related, but they clearly are not. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I need to configure Webpack such that it loads the dependencies before running index.js (currently set as the entry point).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the fix was altering the entry point in my webpack config file. I changed the entry point from:

```
entry: '/index.js'
```

to

```
entry: [SRC_DIR + '/views/main.js', SRC_DIR + '/index.js']
```

This ensured the dependencies(in main.js) were loaded first, followed by the index.js file. Hence in the bundled output file, the dependencies (in this case Book view) were implemented before initializing them. The problem was thus not in the code I posted, but in the configuration file of Webpack.